# Two Table Views, Two Models

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

Is it possible to have one data model that populates 2 or more tableviews? I am using 2 models at the moment and have been having some trouble:

```
class Soccer: Object {
  dynamic var player = ""
  dynamic var highscore = ""
  dynamic var talents = ""
}

class Cricket: Object {
  dynamic var player = ""
  dynamic var highscore = ""
  dynamic var talents = ""
}
```

1 tableview is supposed to get data from the `Soccer` model, the 2nd tableview from the `Cricket` model. I am using `Realm.isEmpty` to check if I have a Realm when the app launches, located in my AppDelegate:

```
class SetUpData {
static func defaults() {

    let realm = try! Realm()

    guard realm.isEmpty else { return }

    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(Article.self())
    }
  }
}
```

This pre-populates my `SoccerTableViewController` UI. But I cannot achieve the same result with `CricketTableViewController.` I am doing everything in code and am trying to learn the best way to go about populating multiple tableviews using Realm Swift.

Comment: Why do you populate your database with `Article` object if you need `Cricket` or `Soccer` objects? `Realm.isEmpty` won't be true once you add an (any type of) object to it, so you have to add `Soccer` and `Cricket` objects after that `guard` statement. Or you can check separately if your db contains both type of data by query for them like: `realm.objects(Cricket.self).count == 0` and `realm.objects(Soccer.self).count == 0`.

Comment: Sorry. I was copy and pasting from another project. `Article.self()` should be `Soccer.self()

Comment: You can use interface or superclass to hold concrete objects of Soccer and cricket.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean like this?

```
class Sport: Object {
  dynamic var player = ""
  dynamic var highscore = ""
  dynamic var talents = ""
}

class Soccer: Sport {
  // ...
}

class Cricket: Sport {
  // ...
}

class SportTableViewController: UIViewController {

    var tableViewDatas: [Sport]?

    // ...
}

class SoccerTableViewController: SportTableViewController {

    // ...
}

class CricketTableViewController: SportTableViewController {

    // ...
}
```

Comment: This looks good! Possibly. Will check tomorrow. It's late. Give me a day please. I'm wiped. It's 4:07 am where I am :0

Comment: Sorry for the delay. This doesn't work. In Realm, model classes inherit from `Object` not other classes. There are `Lists` which function like arrays, but I have not figured out how to use them in a way to accomplish this task.

Comment: Have you tried to make `Sport` inherit from `Object`? as I update

Comment: Yes. You cannot do that. `Inheritance from a final class.`

Comment: **Solution - as it were** Create a new model for each tableview and filter and/or sort via that, including notification tokens, cell content, everything. Apologies for the amateur understanding. Be well!